# NSLocale Swift 3

Tags: swift, currency, swift3, nslocale

How do I get the currency symbol in Swift 3?

```
public class Currency: NSObject {
    public let name: String
    public let code: String
    public var symbol: String {
        return NSLocale.currentLocale().displayNameForKey(NSLocaleCurrencySymbol, value: code) ?? ""
    }

    // MARK: NSObject

    public init(name: String, code: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.code = code
        super.init()
    }
}
```

I know NSLocale got renamed to Locale, but displayNameForKey got removed and I only seem to be able to use localizedString(forCurrencyCode: self.code) to generate the name of the currency in the current locale without being able to get its symbol. I'm looking for a way to get a foreign currency symbol in a current locale.

Or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`NSLocale` was not renamed, it still exists. `Locale` is a
new type introduced in Swift 3 as a value type wrapper
(compare [SE-0069 Mutability and Foundation Value Types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0069-swift-mutability-for-foundation.md)).

Apparently `Locale` has no `displayName(forKey:value:)` method,
but you can always convert it to its Foundation counterpart
`NSLocale`:

```
public var symbol: String {
    return (Locale.current as NSLocale).displayName(forKey: .currencySymbol, value: code) ?? ""
}
```

More examples:

```
// Dollar symbol in the german locale:
let s1 = (Locale(identifier:"de") as NSLocale).displayName(forKey: .currencySymbol, value: "USD")!
print(s1) // $

// Dollar symbol in the italian locale:
let s2 = (Locale(identifier:"it") as NSLocale).displayName(forKey: .currencySymbol, value: "USD")!
print(s2) // US$
```

Comment: Thank you this works and looks a lot neater than the solution I made by using a global Objective-C function.

Answer (score 5):

```
Locale.current.currencySymbol
```

The new `Locale` type moved most of the stringly typed properties into real properties. See the [developer pages](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nslocale/1642814-currencysymbol) for the full list of properties.

Comment: That only works for the currency symbol of the current locale.

Comment: I was looking for a foreign currency symbol in the current locale. Not for a foreign currency code in a foreign locale.

Answer (score 2):

I use extension for Locale 
this is my code

```
extension Int {
func asLocaleCurrency(identifier: String) -> String {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: identifier)
    return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(integerLiteral: self))!
}
}
```

and this for use

```
var priceCount = 100000
priceCount.asLocaleCurrency(identifier: "id_ID")
```

Answer (score 0):

For swift 3

```
locale.regionCode
```

regionsCode is similar to the displayName

Answer (score 0):

There is a function to get localized name of a currency code in the `Locale` directly no need to cast to `NSLocale`.

```swift
Locale(identifier: "en-GB").localizedString(forCurrencyCode: "USD") // "Us Dollar"
Locale(identifier: "pl-PL").localizedString(forCurrencyCode: "USD") // "Dolar Amerykański"
```