# NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3

What's the `Notification.Name` equivalent for `NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification`?

Comment: NSLocale.currentLocaleDidChangeNotification is the equivalent of NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification as Martin R said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [`NSLocale` reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nslocale) there is

```
class let currentLocaleDidChangeNotification: NSNotification.Name
// Notification that indicates that the user’s locale changed.
```

which you can use as

```
let notification = NSLocale.currentLocaleDidChangeNotification
```

Comment: Silly me thinking it would be in the newer Locale class ;)

Comment: Yes, the overlay type Locale does not provide all NSLocale methods. Here is another example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519144/nslocale-swift-3