# How to get country code using NSLocale in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, nslocale

Could you please help on how to get country code using `NSLocale` in `Swift 3` ?

This is the previous code I have been using.

```
NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode) as! String
```

I can get Language Code as below in Swift 3.

```
Locale.current.languageCode!
```

As I can see, fetching languageCode is straight forward but countryCode property is not available.

Comment: The same approach as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/39519359/1187415 works here as well: `(Locale.current as NSLocale).object(forKey: .countryCode)`.

Comment: I can see working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: let locale = Locale.current
print(locale.regionCode)

Comment: I guess regionCode different than countryCode?

Comment: @MartinR I have edited this for your review

Comment: @MartinR This does not appear to be a duplicate. This question is asking about country code not currency

Comment: @Daniel: It is the same problem with the same solution: You have to cast the locale to `NSLocale`. See my first comment which OP confirmed.

Comment: Here's the answer for this question: let countryCode = (NSLocale.current as NSLocale).object(forKey: NSLocale.Key.countryCode) as? String. I believe this question should be re-opened - and not marked as a duplicate - although the resolution strategy is similar.

Comment: @Daniel: As you please :)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

*See [Wojciech N.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39769250/1187415)
for a simpler solution!*

---

Similarly as in [NSLocale Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519144/nslocale-swift-3), you have to cast the overlay type `Locale` back to its
Foundation counterpart `NSLocale` in order to retrieve the country code:

```
if let countryCode = (Locale.current as NSLocale).object(forKey: .countryCode) as? String {
    print(countryCode)
}
```

Comment: There is no need to cast it, just use `Locale.regionCode` they are the same, check my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60450519/777350

Answer (score 90):

You can use regionCode property on Locale struct.

```
Locale.current.regionCode
```

It is not documented as a substitute for old NSLocaleCountryCode construct but it looks like it is. The following code checks countryCodes for all known locales and compares them with regionCodes. They are identical.

```
public func ==(lhs: [String?], rhs: [String?]) -> Bool {
    guard lhs.count == rhs.count else { return false }

    for (left, right) in zip(lhs, rhs) {
        if left != right {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}

let newIdentifiers = Locale.availableIdentifiers
let newLocales = newIdentifiers.map { Locale(identifier: $0) }
let newCountryCodes = newLocales.map { $0.regionCode }

let oldIdentifiers = NSLocale.availableLocaleIdentifiers
newIdentifiers == oldIdentifiers // true

let oldLocales = oldIdentifiers.map { NSLocale(localeIdentifier: $0) }
let oldLocalesConverted = oldLocales.map { $0 as Locale }
newLocales == oldLocalesConverted // true

let oldComponents = oldIdentifiers.map { NSLocale.components(fromLocaleIdentifier: $0) }
let oldCountryCodes = oldComponents.map { $0[NSLocale.Key.countryCode.rawValue] }
newCountryCodes == oldCountryCodes // true
```

Comment: Nicely done! Love it that you essentially proved your conjecture. I know the selected answer is technically correct, but oh how I hate that bridging to NSLocale.

Comment: It's really interesting. The language code (I know here is region) is only the right one, when the localizables existing in the app. 
For example you have in your app localizables for german and english. When you set your phone on language french, the language code won't be french rather the last known language code or a default one.

Comment: There is no need to cast it, just use `Locale.regionCode` they are the same, check my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60450519/777350

Answer (score 8):

If you make sure that you're using an `NSLocale` and not a `Locale` instance, you can use the `countryCode` property:

```
let locale: NSLocale = NSLocale.current as NSLocale
let country: String? = locale.countryCode
print(country ?? "no country")
// > Prints "IE" or some other country code
```

If you try to use `countryCode` with a Swift `Locale` Xcode will give you an error with a suggestion to use `regionCode` instead:

```
let swiftLocale: Locale = Locale.current
let swiftCountry: String? = swiftLocale.countryCode
// > Error "countryCode' is unavailable: use regionCode instead"
```

Answer (score 7):

`NSLocale.countryCode` is the same as `Locale.regionCode`

This is from apple implementation of `Locale`. [Locale.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/Sources/Foundation/Locale.swift)

```
    /// Returns the region code of the locale, or nil if it has none.
    ///
    /// For example, for the locale "zh-Hant-HK", returns "HK".
    public var regionCode: String? {
        // n.b. this is called countryCode in ObjC
        if let result = _wrapped.object(forKey: .countryCode) as? String {
            if result.isEmpty {
                return nil
            } else {
                return result
            }
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, what is wrapped?  it gives me error. should i declare it?

Comment: Just use `Locale.current.regionCode`

Comment: ok thank you. I have already used that. but i like to know your method. So asked.

Answer (score 4):

### iOS 16 *

```
print(Locale.current.region?.identifier)
```

### Below iOS 16

```
print(Locale.current.regionCode)
```

### example:

```
var localCode: String? = ""
        
if #available(iOS 16, *)  {
    localCode = Locale.current.region?.identifier
} else {
    localCode = Locale.current.regionCode
}
print(localCode)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//MARK:- Get both country code and Mobile Phone number code
        var sendPhoneNumber = ""

                if let countryCode = (Locale.current as NSLocale).object(forKey: .countryCode) as? String {
                     print(countryCode)

                    if countryCode != ""
                    {
                       let getCode = self.getCountryPhonceCode(countryCode)

                        if getCode != ""
                        {
                            sendPhoneNumber = getCode + tfMobileNumber.text!
                            getOTP(getPhoneNumber: sendPhoneNumber)
                        }
                    }
                }

     //MARK:- Custom methods

     func getCountryPhonceCode (_ country : String) -> String
    {
        var countryDictionary  = ["AF":"93",
                                  "AL":"355",
                                  "DZ":"213",
                                  "AS":"1",
                                  "AD":"376",
                                  "AO":"244",
                                  "AI":"1",
                                  "AG":"1",
                                  "AR":"54",
                                  "AM":"374",
                                  "AW":"297",
                                  "AU":"61",
                                  "AT":"43",
                                  "AZ":"994",
                                  "BS":"1",
                                  "BH":"973",
                                  "BD":"880",
                                  "BB":"1",
                                  "BY":"375",
                                  "BE":"32",
                                  "BZ":"501",
                                  "BJ":"229",
                                  "BM":"1",
                                  "BT":"975",
                                  "BA":"387",
                                  "BW":"267",
                                  "BR":"55",
                                  "IO":"246",
                                  "BG":"359",
                                  "BF":"226",
                                  "BI":"257",
                                  "KH":"855",
                                  "CM":"237",
                                  "CA":"1",
                                  "CV":"238",
                                  "KY":"345",
                                  "CF":"236",
                                  "TD":"235",
                                  "CL":"56",
                                  "CN":"86",
                                  "CX":"61",
                                  "CO":"57",
                                  "KM":"269",
                                  "CG":"242",
                                  "CK":"682",
                                  "CR":"506",
                                  "HR":"385",
                                  "CU":"53",
                                  "CY":"537",
                                  "CZ":"420",
                                  "DK":"45",
                                  "DJ":"253",
                                  "DM":"1",
                                  "DO":"1",
                                  "EC":"593",
                                  "EG":"20",
                                  "SV":"503",
                                  "GQ":"240",
                                  "ER":"291",
                                  "EE":"372",
                                  "ET":"251",
                                  "FO":"298",
                                  "FJ":"679",
                                  "FI":"358",
                                  "FR":"33",
                                  "GF":"594",
                                  "PF":"689",
                                  "GA":"241",
                                  "GM":"220",
                                  "GE":"995",
                                  "DE":"49",
                                  "GH":"233",
                                  "GI":"350",
                                  "GR":"30",
                                  "GL":"299",
                                  "GD":"1",
                                  "GP":"590",
                                  "GU":"1",
                                  "GT":"502",
                                  "GN":"224",
                                  "GW":"245",
                                  "GY":"595",
                                  "HT":"509",
                                  "HN":"504",
                                  "HU":"36",
                                  "IS":"354",
                                  "IN":"91",
                                  "ID":"62",
                                  "IQ":"964",
                                  "IE":"353",
                                  "IL":"972",
                                  "IT":"39",
                                  "JM":"1",
                                  "JP":"81",
                                  "JO":"962",
                                  "KZ":"77",
                                  "KE":"254",
                                  "KI":"686",
                                  "KW":"965",
                                  "KG":"996",
                                  "LV":"371",
                                  "LB":"961",
                                  "LS":"266",
                                  "LR":"231",
                                  "LI":"423",
                                  "LT":"370",
                                  "LU":"352",
                                  "MG":"261",
                                  "MW":"265",
                                  "MY":"60",
                                  "MV":"960",
                                  "ML":"223",
                                  "MT":"356",
                                  "MH":"692",
                                  "MQ":"596",
                                  "MR":"222",
                                  "MU":"230",
                                  "YT":"262",
                                  "MX":"52",
                                  "MC":"377",
                                  "MN":"976",
                                  "ME":"382",
                                  "MS":"1",
                                  "MA":"212",
                                  "MM":"95",
                                  "NA":"264",
                                  "NR":"674",
                                  "NP":"977",
                                  "NL":"31",
                                  "AN":"599",
                                  "NC":"687",
                                  "NZ":"64",
                                  "NI":"505",
                                  "NE":"227",
                                  "NG":"234",
                                  "NU":"683",
                                  "NF":"672",
                                  "MP":"1",
                                  "NO":"47",
                                  "OM":"968",
                                  "PK":"92",
                                  "PW":"680",
                                  "PA":"507",
                                  "PG":"675",
                                  "PY":"595",
                                  "PE":"51",
                                  "PH":"63",
                                  "PL":"48",
                                  "PT":"351",
                                  "PR":"1",
                                  "QA":"974",
                                  "RO":"40",
                                  "RW":"250",
                                  "WS":"685",
                                  "SM":"378",
                                  "SA":"966",
                                  "SN":"221",
                                  "RS":"381",
                                  "SC":"248",
                                  "SL":"232",
                                  "SG":"65",
                                  "SK":"421",
                                  "SI":"386",
                                  "SB":"677",
                                  "ZA":"27",
                                  "GS":"500",
                                  "ES":"34",
                                  "LK":"94",
                                  "SD":"249",
                                  "SR":"597",
                                  "SZ":"268",
                                  "SE":"46",
                                  "CH":"41",
                                  "TJ":"992",
                                  "TH":"66",
                                  "TG":"228",
                                  "TK":"690",
                                  "TO":"676",
                                  "TT":"1",
                                  "TN":"216",
                                  "TR":"90",
                                  "TM":"993",
                                  "TC":"1",
                                  "TV":"688",
                                  "UG":"256",
                                  "UA":"380",
                                  "AE":"971",
                                  "GB":"44",
                                  "US":"1",
                                  "UY":"598",
                                  "UZ":"998",
                                  "VU":"678",
                                  "WF":"681",
                                  "YE":"967",
                                  "ZM":"260",
                                  "ZW":"263",
                                  "BO":"591",
                                  "BN":"673",
                                  "CC":"61",
                                  "CD":"243",
                                  "CI":"225",
                                  "FK":"500",
                                  "GG":"44",
                                  "VA":"379",
                                  "HK":"852",
                                  "IR":"98",
                                  "IM":"44",
                                  "JE":"44",
                                  "KP":"850",
                                  "KR":"82",
                                  "LA":"856",
                                  "LY":"218",
                                  "MO":"853",
                                  "MK":"389",
                                  "FM":"691",
                                  "MD":"373",
                                  "MZ":"258",
                                  "PS":"970",
                                  "PN":"872",
                                  "RE":"262",
                                  "RU":"7",
                                  "BL":"590",
                                  "SH":"290",
                                  "KN":"1",
                                  "LC":"1",
                                  "MF":"590",
                                  "PM":"508",
                                  "VC":"1",
                                  "ST":"239",
                                  "SO":"252",
                                  "SJ":"47",
                                  "SY":"963",
                                  "TW":"886",
                                  "TZ":"255",
                                  "TL":"670",
                                  "VE":"58",
                                  "VN":"84",
                                  "VG":"284",
                                  "VI":"340"]
        if countryDictionary[country] != nil {
            return countryDictionary[country]!
        }

        else {
            return ""
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With Swift 5, it's just:

```
let countryCode = Locale.current.region?.identifier
```

Answer (score -7):

```
print(NSLocale.current.regionCode)
```

Comment: This is the same as @wojciech-n's answer from 2016... except it's obsolete (it should be Locale in Swift 3, instead of NSLocale which is for Swift 2).