# How to get systemLocaleCountryCode in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift2, swift3, locale, nslocale

i swift 2 i was getting the systemLocale using the bellow code:

```
let systemLocaleCountryCode = NSLocale.systemLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode) as? String
```

but now i in swift 3 , i am receiving the bellow error :

> cannot call value of non function type locale

then once i changed it to :

```
 let systemLocaleCountryCode = NSLocale.systemLocale.objectForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode) as? String
```

I've received another error:

> value of type Locale has no member objectForKey

what's the problem ? How to fix it ?

Comment: Does `NSLocale.system.regionCode` return the expected value?

Comment: Related: [How to get country code using NSLocale in Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39596238/how-to-get-country-code-using-nslocale-in-swift-3)

Comment: @MartinR, thank you

Comment: @vadian thank you for your comment , no it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift3
change to

```
let systemLocaleCountryCode = (NSLocale.system as NSLocale).object(forKey: .countryCode) as? String
```

Answer (score 2):

use like

```
 if let systemLocaleCountryCode = (Locale.system as NSLocale).object(forKey: .countryCode) as? String {
print(systemLocaleCountryCode)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but now i received this error  : system is unavailable consider using the user's locale or nil instead depending on use case

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if let systemLocaleCountryCode = (Locale.current as NSLocale).object(forKey: .countryCode) as? String
    {
        print(systemLocaleCountryCode)
    }
```