# Is it possible to have two different UI for a program?

Tags: swift, multilingual

Is it possible to have a program built for two countries and change the appearance and language of the program due to the SIM card code on the device?

Comment: You can simply in the first ask for his mobile number to verify his login/register, you can check the prefix of the number if it was valid and swizzle whatever you need based on that .

Comment: You get current country code of device use of "Locale" in swift and set custom ui based on country selection. Or access of simcard contact number and identified the country and set UI regarding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can check user's language for this.

Get the language key of localization:

```
let preferredLanguage = NSLocale.preferredLanguages.first
```

Also you can get [country code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39596238/how-to-get-country-code-using-nslocale-in-swift-3).

Also you can do it using user's location, but I think it is a bad approach. Location requires a lof of battery.